# Body Still detect collision after setting maskbit and category

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have set maskbits and categorybits of my body. But why collision is still detected between object that is not supposed to be detected?

Body 1:

```
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.position.set( 5, 2);

    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius(getWidth() /GC.UNITS_PER_METER /7);

    fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 1;
    fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = GC.CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH;
    fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = GC.MASK_MONSTER_MOUTH;

    Body box = world.createBody(def);
    box.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    circleShape.dispose();

    sensorBody= box;
    sensorBody.setFixedRotation(true);
    sensorBody.setAwake(true);
    sensorBody.setUserData(this);
```

Body 2:

```
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.position.set(getX() - (getWidth()* getScaleX()) , getY() - (getHeight() * getScaleY()));

    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius(box2dWidth/2);

    fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.friction=0.5f;
    fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = GC.CATEGORY_MONSTER;
    fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = GC.MASK_MONSTER;
    Body box = world.createBody(def);
    box.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    polygonShape.dispose();

    body = box;
    body.setAwake(true);
    body.setUserData(this);
    body.setAngularDamping(4);
    body.setFixedRotation(true);
```

My categories details:

```
public static final short CATEGORY_ARROW = 0x0001; // 0000000000000001 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER = 0x0002; // 0000000000000010 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_SCENERY = 0x0004; // 0000000000000100 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_GRAVEYARD = 0x0008; // 0000000000000100 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_PENGUIN = 0X0016;
public static final short CATEGORY_FISH = 0x0032;
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH = 0x0064;

public static final short MASK_ARROW = CATEGORY_MONSTER | CATEGORY_SCENERY; 
public static final short MASK_MONSTER = CATEGORY_ARROW | CATEGORY_SCENERY ; 
public static final short MASK_PENGUIN = CATEGORY_SCENERY | CATEGORY_MONSTER; 
public static final short MASK_FISH = CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH| CATEGORY_SCENERY; 
public static final short MASK_GRAVEYARD = CATEGORY_SCENERY;
public static final short MASK_MONSTER_MOUTH = CATEGORY_FISH | CATEGORY_SCENERY;
```

Body1 and body2 are not supposed colliding each other, but I failed to acheive it by setting maskbits and categorybits. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CATEGORY values in Hex are wrong. Currently the values of your CATEGORYs are:

```
public static final short CATEGORY_ARROW = 0x0001; // 1 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER = 0x0002; // 10 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_SCENERY = 0x0004; // 100 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_GRAVEYARD = 0x0008; // 1000 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_PENGUIN = 0X0016; // 10110 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_FISH = 0x0032; // 110010 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH = 0x0064; // 1100100 in binary
```

So `MASK_MONSTER = CATEGORY_MONSTER | CATEGORY_SCENERY` = 110 in binary
And `CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH` = 1100100 in binary

Finally, `MASK_MONSTER | CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH` will match because it results in 100

---

**Your problem is that your count up in Hex is wrong you must write:**

```
public static final short CATEGORY_ARROW = 0x0001; // 1 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER = 0x0002; // 10 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_SCENERY = 0x0004; // 100 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_GRAVEYARD = 0x0008; // 1000 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_PENGUIN = 0X0010; // 10000 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_FISH = 0x0020; // 100000 in binary
public static final short CATEGORY_MONSTER_MOUTH = 0x0040; // 1000000 in binary
```

After that comes 0x80, 0x100, 0x200, 0x400, 0x800, 0x1000 etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can i make such a careless mistake. Will make further study on Hex value after this.

Comment: @Pengyou good idea. The values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 you can also use but then you must remove the 0x before the numbers and then they are in decimal and it will also work.